# How do I adjust this python script to backup to Amazon S3

Tags: python, centos5, amazon-s3

The following script is nearly perfect for my backup needs: http://pastie.org/3368661

However, it only allows you to backup to the server or a remote FTP. I would like to add an option to backup to Amazon S3 (which isn't a standard FTP).

At line 323 is where things would need to start changing.

I was going to ask for also the ability to delete old backs up on S3, but it seems Amazon now offers that feature through their console so it shouldn't be needed here.

If someone can't figure out a way to do this in this script, the second option would be to backup to a server folder, and then use an open source project such as s3sync.rb but that would not be ideal.

This is for a MediaTemple DV Server running Centos 5 and Plesk 10. Thanks in advance!

Found more info: http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/(dv)_4.0:Setup_s3fs_to_easily_use_Amazon_S3

Comment: My second link provided enough help to resolve it. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I tend to just dump stuff to one place on the filesystem (typically /var/backups) and then backup the filesystem using something like for example duplicity that happens to support S3.

Comment: Yes, that's my second option I mentioned in my post, but this post in search of a solution of modifying the existing python script. Tbut thanks!